# SQL to produce matches from a data table and a pattern table

Tags: sql, database-cursor

Given a data table with columns id, color, size and a second table with rules/patterns so rule_id, color_condition and size_condition.

So a basic rule would be rule_id=1,Color=blue, size=Any or rule_id=2,Color=blue, size=15

How can I construct a SQL query that produces matches into a third table

For example for an entry in the data table id=1, color=blue, size=10 both rules would apply and therefor the matches table would cotain two entries

```
rule_id=1, entry_id=1
rule_id=2, entry_id=1
```

How To cycle through the patterns and how to construct the matching so that it can deal with wildcards or omit conditions if they are empty.

Please provide directions or keywords, I am ready to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the rule table :

```
Rule
Id--Color--Size
1 --blue -- null
2 --blue -- 15
```

And Entry table

```
Entry
Id--Color--Size
1 --blue -- 10
```

Put a null value instead of a 'Any' value to keep some strong typing

A solution :

```
Select r.id as rule_id,
       e.id as entry_id
From Entry e inner join Rule r
          On (e.Color = r.Color or r.Color is null)
          And (e.Size <= r.Size or r.Size is null)
```

You can create a new table Color for better performance :

```
Color
Id--Name
1 --Red
2 --Blue

Rule
Id--Id_Color--Size
1 --  2     -- null
2 --  2     -- 15

Entry
Id--Id_Color--Size
1 --   2    -- 10

Select r.id as rule_id,
       e.id as entry_id
From Entry e inner join Rule r
     On  (e.Id_Color = r.Id_Color or r.Color is null)
     And (e.Size <= r.Size or r.Size is null)
```

Add an index to both Id_Colors